# how to create smart pointer here when function have return type

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

How to used smart pointer here when function have return type

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int* getStorage()
{
    int* storage = new int[10];
    return storage;
}


int main()
{
    int*  storage = getStorage();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        storage[i] = i;
    }
    
    delete storage;
    storage = NULL;
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: interviewer asked me how to used smart pointer here, take care dynamic allocated memory without using delete keyword.

In short run this code using any smart pointer.

Comment: Did they specify what kind of smart pointer? Just returning a `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` should be easy enough, what have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: no any smart pointer, 
don't have that much idea , because of return type.

Comment: let us know your approach for understanding.

Comment: Please don’t do this: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`. Also please don’t do this: `using namespace std;`. Both are (in)famous antipatterns. Change your function to: `std::unique_ptr<int[]> getStorage() { /* use std::make_unique here */ }`.

Comment: This is a valid question as a beginner, dont discourage people by negatively voting it. Already people are saying stack overflow is toxic : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7v0yvdkIHg

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. Dynamically allocated arrays are supported for shared pointers since c++17.

```
    auto getStorage()
    {
      return std::shared_ptr<int[]>(new int[10]); // Since c++20 you can use std::make_shared<int[]>(10);
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        auto storage = getStorage();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            storage[i] = i;
        }
    
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should understand the memory ownership clearly in such scenarios. Who should be responsible to delete this memory ? In your example it is clear that the caller should own the memory. In this case I would re-write the function like below :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

std::unique_ptr<int[]> getStorage()
{
    auto storage = make_unique<int[]>(new int[10]);
    return std::move(storage); // Move may not be needed if copy elision happens in compiler
}


int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> storage = getStorage();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        storage[i] = i;
    }
    
    cout<<endl;
}
```

By using std::move() the memory ownership is transferred from getStorage() function to the caller function. It will get destroyed when the caller function finishes the execution automatically.